# Django: Annotate value based on related set

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm looking for a way to annotate value of aggregated filtered related set.

```
class Location(...
    ...

class Ticket(...
    location = ForeignKey(Location...)
    date = ...
    price = ...
```

I need to annotate maximal price of ticket in a daterange.

So if I set only last 30 days, it returns me all `Location` objects and every object have 'max_price' annotation which equals to maximal price of the tickets from last 30 days.

Tickets:

```
<Ticket France 100 now-50days>
<Ticket France 200 now-20days->
<Ticket France 300 now-20days>
<Ticket Austria 200 now-10days>
<Ticket Austria 50 now-10days>
```

In this case, queryset returns:

```
<Location France> + annotated 200
<Location Austria> + annotated 50
```

Is it possible to do it in one `Query`?

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you include the actual queryset and annotation calls.

Comment: you said 'max_price', but in your expected result i saw annotated 200 and 50. It 'minimum' of last 30 days ?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
from django.db.models import Case, Max, Q
date = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)

events = Locations.objects.annotate(
    max_price=Max('ticket_set__price', filter=Q(ticket_set__date__gte=date))
)
```

Do note that I'm using `ticket_set` here because I don't know if you have a `related_name` on the foreign key or not. If you do have a related name like `tickets`, use that  instead of `ticket_set`.